# Matching of tuples

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, tuples

From what I understood I can use pattern-matching in a `match ... with` expression with tuples of values, so something like

```
match b with
  ("<",  val) -> if v < val then true else false
| ("<=", val) -> if v <= val then true else false
```

should be correct but it gives me a syntax error as if the parenthesis couldn't be used:

> File "ocaml.ml", line 41, characters 14-17:
> Error: Syntax error: ')' expected

> File "ocaml.ml", line 41, characters 8-9:
> Error: This '(' might be unmatched

referring on first match clause..

Apart from that, can I avoid matching strings and applying comparisons using a sort of eval of the string? Or using directly the comparison operator as the first element of the tuple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`val` is a reserved keyword in OCaml, so you can't use it as a variable name. If you use something else instead of `val`, it will work.

As a side note: `if condition then true else false` is equivalent to `condition`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the core of your problem, but a more flexible (*and potentially performant as the lookup map grows*) approach to this problem may be to use a map of strings to functions, and then use the lookup functions in the map to handle the dispatch.

```
module StrMap = Map.Make (String)
```

```
# let eval_binary_op op a b =
    StrMap.(
      let m =
        empty
        |> add "<" (<)
        |> add "<=" (<=)
      in
      match find_opt op m with
      | None -> failwith "op not found"
      | Some f -> f a b
    );; 
val eval_binary_op : string -> 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
# eval_binary_op "<" 4 5;;
- : bool = true
# eval_binary_op "<" 7 5;;
- : bool = false
# eval_binary_op ">" 7 5;;
Exception: Failure "op not found".
```